# Convert object from one class to another in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have 2 custom classes A and B.
Now I have an object of A let say 'a' and have to convert it to B class.

Now I have 2 approach

- First is I write a transform Util which has a static method for conversion.
- The second approach is to write that logic in class A with a method convertToB()

Which one is more accurate. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right forum for these kind of questions. "Which one is more accurate" has only opinion based answers and no "correct answer". Have a look at `Integer.parseInt( someString )` with it's homologue `Integer.valueOf ( someString )` and even an utils method in Apache utils. Both attempts are correct. If you are switching often between A and B, then you might want a "convertTo" but if you use it only a few times, maybe an Utils method would be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it depends on the relationship between A and B.

If B extends A the conversion is done within the language when assigning an A object to a B object.

Otherwise, if there is no inheritance at play, it would be advised to either create a util class to do the conversion for the case of future changes, or have a constructor of B that has an A object as a parameter.

Comment: Good idea with the constructor

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference and a question perhaps better suited for the software engineering/design counterpart to Stack Overflow. That said, I would use the first option. If you ever add more classes and need to convert between them, you will bloat your classes with all the conversion methods. If you have one or more classes with the conversion methods, the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of Concerns - util class is the best approach